# How to find pairs of events with postgres?

Tags: psql

I have an events table:

```
             ts             |  user  | reason 
----------------------------+--------+--------
 2018-06-01 10:44:15.52+01  | 359999 | START
 2018-06-01 10:44:29.521+01 | 359999 | STOP
 2018-06-01 10:44:43.52+01  | 359998 | START
 2018-06-01 10:44:55.52+01  | 359999 | START
 2018-06-01 10:44:59.521+01 | 359998 | STOP
 2018-06-01 10:45:07.52+01  | 359999 | STOP
 2018-06-01 10:46:16.52+01  | 359999 | START
```

And I want to find the pairs of events:

```
  user  |           start            |            stop            
--------+----------------------------+----------------------------
 359999 | 2018-06-01 10:44:15.52+01  | 2018-06-01 10:44:29.521+01
 359998 | 2018-06-01 10:44:43.52+01  | 2018-06-01 10:44:59.521+01
 359999 | 2018-06-01 10:44:55.52+01  | 2018-06-01 10:45:07.52+01
 359999 | 2018-06-01 10:46:16.52+01  |
```

What sort of query could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html). Among other things, these let you reference the next/previous row in a query result (via `lead()` and `lag()`). For example:

```
SELECT "user", ts AS start, next_ts AS stop
FROM (
  SELECT *, lead(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY "user" ORDER BY ts) AS next_ts
  FROM events
  WHERE reason IN ('START', 'STOP')
) AS ts_pairs
WHERE reason = 'START'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just got this working.  Is there a more efficient way?

```
select imei, reason, ts AS start, (
    select ts
    from events as stops
    where stops.ts > starts.ts
    and reason = 'STOP'
    and stops.user = starts.user
    order by ts desc
    limit 1
) as stop
from events as starts
where reason = 'START'
order by ts
;
```