# How to do logical operations on time periods in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, period

I have some time periods:

```
Mobile Event Time
  A    START 13:00
  B    START 13:05
  A    STOP  14:00
  B    STOP  14:05
  A    START 15:00
  A    STOP  16:00
```

How can I do logical operations on such data, such that I can get:

```
Mobile Event Time
A | B  START 13:00
A | B  STOP  14:05
A | B  START 15:00
A | B  STOP  16:00
```

and

```
Mobile Event Time
A & B  START 13:05
A & B  STOP  14:00
```

Comment: Why the vote to close?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly, then "logical operations" is probably not the best way to describe these; they're really set intersection and union operations (though the two are strongly related).

Postgres' [range operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html) can calculate unions and intersections, so it might help to start by pairing up the start/end timestamps (as in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50641682)) to build [`tsrange` values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html).

Once that's in place, finding the intersection (`A & B`) is relatively straightforward:

```
WITH time_pair AS (
  SELECT *, lead("time") OVER (PARTITION BY mobile ORDER BY "time") AS next_time
  FROM events
  WHERE event IN ('START', 'STOP')
),
time_range AS (
  SELECT mobile, tsrange("time", next_time) AS period
  FROM time_pair
  WHERE event = 'START'
)
SELECT 'A & B', a_range.period * b_range.period
FROM time_range a_range
JOIN time_range b_range ON
  a_range.period && b_range.period
WHERE
  a_range.mobile = 'A' AND
  b_range.mobile = 'B';
```

The union (`A | B`) is a bit more involved; if a range overlaps on both ends, then there are (at least) three ranges contributing to every output row, so a single `JOIN` won't be enough.

On the other hand, this problem is a bit more general, as you can just merge any overlapping ranges together with no regard for exactly which user they came from, so it's a bit easier to find existing implementations. [This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/100965) seems fairly comprehensive. You can find a few more by searching for ["postgres range aggregation"](https://www.google.com/search?q=postgres+range+aggregation).